# Stop duplication of passportjs isAuthenticated code in Express route files

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using passportjs for my authentication.

I have lots of different routes throughout the project, 95% of them require the following function:

```
 // Middleware functions
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
     if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

At the moment, I am putting this function at the bottom of EVERY route file.

Is there a way to write it once, and be able to use it in all the route files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add that middleware before the routes that require it, all requests will pass through it before they get forwarded to the correct route handler:

```
// doesn't require an authenticated request
app.use(router1);         

// add the middleware just once
app.use(isAuthenticated); 

// all following route(r)s require an authenticated request
app.use(router2);         
app.use(router3);
...
```